# Angular - linking to a ngInclude partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

I have followed the documentation on setting up [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) and have it working (loading in HTML partials) and changing the partial when a select option is changed.

```
$scope.templates = [
    { name: 'Overview', url: 'partials/project/overview.html' },
    { name: 'Tasks', url: 'partials/project/tasks.html' }
];
$scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

----

<div ng-controller="Tasks">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
        <option value="">(blank)</option>
    </select>

    <section ng-include="template.url"></section>
</div>
```

However, I don't want to use a select menu to navigate. I want to use an unordered list. I tried using `ngHref`, but that doesn't seem to work. I can't find much documentation on binding an element to change an `ngInclude` partial, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Any help on how I could use anchor tags to change the partial being loaded in on click would be great.

Here's the structure I was playing around with:

```
<ul class="header-menu">
    <li><a ng-modal="template" ng-href="{{template[0]}}" class="selected">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a ng-modal="template" ng-href="{{template[1]}}">Tasks</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there is no "ngModal" directive in AngularJS core.

Comment: Ah right, that was a typo and I since it fixed it to `ng-model`. Not that it helped anyway though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to store the path to your template, and change it based on an action in your list. ngHref isn't related here, because it would load the template itself which isn't what you want.

See this demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6RmDPL9CxSYUA9TGVANq?p=preview):

HTML:

```
     <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="template in templates">
      {{template.name}}
      <button ng-click="selectTemplate(template)">Go!</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {{selectedTemplate}}
    <div ng-include="selectedTemplate"></div>
  </body>
```

Controller:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.templates=[{
    name:'First Template',
    url:'template1.html'
  }
  ,{
    name:'Second Template',
    url:'template2.html'
  }
  ]

  $scope.selectedTemplate=$scope.templates[0].url;
  $scope.selectTemplate=function(template){
    $scope.selectedTemplate=template.url;
  }
});
```

But I really suggest you to check out to check out [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), as it sounds like you are trying to implement some tab system, and changing states for your app, and ui-router does that perfectly.